# Count case "string" on a column

Tags: mysql

I want to do a count on a certain value in a column. Structure looks like this;

```
FieldName       FieldValue
food            fruit
food            fruit
food            fruit
food            vegetable
```

MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT `FieldValue` AS `type`,
COUNT(case when `FieldValue` = 'fruit' then 1 end)AS `counts`
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `FieldName` LIKE '%food%' 
GROUP BY `FieldName`
```

And it returns this what is OK:

```
type        counts
fruit       3
```

But when i change "fruit" into "vegetable" :

```
SELECT `FieldValue` AS `type`,
COUNT(case when `FieldValue` = 'vegetable' then 1 end)AS `counts`
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `FieldName` LIKE '%food%' 
GROUP BY `FieldName`
```

I get this back:

```
type        counts
fruit       1
```

The count is OK but the type is wrong it should be 'vegetable'.
What am i doing wrong here? Maybe the solution is very simple but i just dont see it.

Comment: You need to check Fieldvalue in where condition also there is no need to use case when then here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT `FieldValue` AS `type`,
COUNT(*)AS `counts`
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `FieldName` LIKE '%food%' and `FieldValue` = 'vegetable'
GROUP BY `FieldValue`
```

Notice that in your original query you were grouping by `FieldName` and not `FieldValue`, while `FieldValue` is the field you were using in the select clause.

If you are using MySQL, you should be aware that it will allow you to use aggregate functions where the non-aggregated columns aren't in the `group by` clause. This will throw an error in other RDBMS like Oracle and MS SQL Server, but in MySQL it just leaves you wondering what's going on.

[MySQL Aggregate Functions without GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497082/mysql-aggregate-functions-without-group-by-clause)

Comment: Yes this one did work. I am only using MySQL. I didn't know i could use the 'value' in the WHERE clause. A big thank you!