# SQL query showing nulls when i need a empty set

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using this query but coming up with nulls in all of the columns. how could i get rid of this? So it becomes a Empty set?

```
SELECT players.id, players.room, players.money, players.cellx, players.celly, max(levels.level) as level 
FROM players, levels 
WHERE players.xp - levels.xp >= 0 AND id=12;  

+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
| id | room | money | cellx | celly | level |   
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+   
|NULL| NULL | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |  
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Why the tags "javascript" and "node.js"?

Comment: that's what i'm using it in?

Comment: They have no relevance whatsoever to the question...

Comment: sorry about that any ideas though?

Comment: Don't you get an error for having the `MAX` function in there without an `GROUP BY`? Please enter the query with some data into http://sqlfiddle.com/ and post the link...

Comment: No, it only shows what comes up above

Comment: ¿Is that the real query or you are making some JOINs? That query result must be empty (id=12 implies it can't return id=null results)

Comment: @Troglo MySQL works in mysterious ways... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91f9b/1/0 - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497082/mysql-aggregate-functions-without-group-by-clause

Comment: Sorry, you are right. The MAX has weird effect in your query

Comment: SELECT players.id, players.room, players.money, players.cellx, players.celly, max(levels.level) as level 
FROM players, levels 
WHERE players.xp - levels.xp >= 0 AND id=12
GROUP BY id

Comment: @Troglo Thanks that works, thanks

Comment: You´re welcome. I assumed you wanted to group by player.id

Comment: Note that Troglo's query will take any value for the columns which are not aggregated and not included in the group by. Also, since there is no join condition for the two tables and the result is limited to ID 12 I don't get what the expected outcome would be... so the query now no longer returns rows but I don't think that it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `MAX` aggregate function, MySQL does an implicit `GROUP BY`.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Suggestions:

- Use MySQL 5.7.5 or newer, or set the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting to disable this behavior. You'll get an error message then instead of nonsensical results.
- Don't join with multiple tables in the `FROM`  clause, use ANSI JOIN syntax instead.
- Specify what you're looking for in the question; the query as-is doesn't make any sense to me.
- You might need an explicit `GROUP BY` or window functions `MAX(...) OVER (...)` to compute aggregates.