# I want to select all the data specified from multiple tables, but it only select one data

Tags: php, sql

I have written a SQL query through which I want to select all the related data specified from multiple tables but when I run the query it only retrieve single data but I want to select all the data. Here is my query:

```
    $mysqli->query("SELECT projectDescription, location,budget,date, 
    SUM(ebudget) as expense_budget, SUM(totalAmount) as overtime_budget, 
    SUM(totalPrice) as material_budget FROM projecttable, expensestable, 
    overtimetable,dailyworkusage WHERE 
    expensestable.projectID=projecttable.projectID AND 
    overtimetable.projectID=projecttable.projectID AND 
    dailyworkusage.projectID=projecttable.projectID") or die($mysqli- 
    >error());
```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: As GMB mentioned you likely need group-by. Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497082/mysql-aggregate-functions-without-group-by-clause) for possible explanation. You also need to include mysql tag.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are missing a `GROUP BY` clause (in non-ancient versions of MySQL, you would have met a syntax error). Add this at the end of your query:

```
GROUP BY projectDescription, location, budget, date
```

Also, you do want to use explicit joins instead of old-school, implicit joins. Using aliases for table names is also a good practice. Here is an updated version of your query:

```
SELECT 
    projectDescription, 
    location,
    budget,
    date, 
    SUM(ebudget) as expense_budget, 
    SUM(totalAmount) as overtime_budget, 
    SUM(totalPrice) as material_budget 
FROM projecttable p
INNER JOIN expensestable e ON e.projectID = p.projectID  
INNER JOIN overtimetable o ON o.projectID = p.projectID 
INNER JOIN dailyworkusage d ON d.projectID = p.projectID
GROUP BY 
    projectDescription, 
    location,
    budget,
    date
```

Please add the relevant table prefixes to all these columns (it cannot be told without seeing your actual table structures, that you did not show).

Comment: Now it multiplies every column of SUM by 4

Comment: @Xeroseven: this query returns one record for each combination of `projectDescription, 
    location,
    budget,
    date`. If you want a different cardinality, you can change the columns in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` clause accordingly.