# How do I convert this MySQL query to MSSQL query COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help. how can I convert this MySQL query count into MsSQL query

```
SELECT patientmasters.ID,
patientmasters.HRN,
patientmasters.LastName,
patientmasters.FirstName,
patientmasters.MiddleName,
 count(casehistories.PatientID) as NumberOfRecords        
from patientmasters
left join casehistories
on (patientmasters.ID = casehistories.PatientID)
group by
    patientmasters.ID;
```

Comment: This works in MySql, but it wasn't especially good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497082/mysql-aggregate-functions-without-group-by-clause) could be useful.
For MS SQL Server it should be:

```
SELECT patientmasters.ID,
patientmasters.HRN,
patientmasters.LastName,
patientmasters.FirstName,
patientmasters.MiddleName,
count(casehistories.PatientID) as NumberOfRecords        
from patientmasters
left join casehistories
on (patientmasters.ID = casehistories.PatientID)
group by
    patientmasters.ID,
    patientmasters.HRN,
    patientmasters.LastName,
    patientmasters.FirstName,
    patientmasters.MiddleName;
```

Answer (score 0):

In either database, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select pm.*,
       (select count(*)
        from casehistories ch
        where pm.ID = ch.PatientID
       ) as NumberOfRecords        
from patientmasters pm;
```

In particular, both databases will take advantage of an index on `casehistories(PatientID)`.  This should have better performance by avoiding the outer aggregation.