# incorrect results from MAX and Order by results

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to get the maximum temperature in a 200 record count along with the temperature.
I'm successful in getting the max(temperature) but the date is incorrect.
There must be some "and-ing' in there where 'temperature=temperature' and 'DateAndTime = DateAndTime'

> Blockquote

```
SELECT  DateAndTime, max(Temperature) as MaxTemp, Humidity, BarrPress 
FROM (
      select DateAndTime, Temperature, Humidity,BarrPress 
      from `temp-at-interrupt` 
      order by DateAndTime DESC LIMIT 200
) as T
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should fail, because you have mixed aggregated columns and unaggregated columns -- and there is no `group by`.

Just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from `temp-at-interrupt` t
      order by dateandtime desc
      limit 200
     ) t
order by temperature desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Gordon, MariaDB/MySQL works sometimes without GROUP BY as well right? I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225144/why-does-mysql-allow-group-by-queries-without-aggregate-functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497082/mysql-aggregate-functions-without-group-by-clause)

Comment: @ShriramRamesh . . . In this case, it shouldn't work -- it is invalid SQL.  I mean, MariaDB might allow the SQL and do something indeterminate, but it is best to keep only full group by mode on and to never rely on such behavior.

Comment: Fantastic...Thanks so much.
For my info: what is diff from aggragated and unaggragated ?