# Query left join fetch data problem - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I join two tables with left join. When I select all with Select, all rows come (query1). But when I pull some rows with select, I load only one data, not all data in Figure 1 is loaded. What is the reason?

[image: query1]
[image: query2]

Loading all data query1

**query1:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM oc_review AS OYLAMA 
JOIN oc_product AS PRODUCT 
    ON (PRODUCT.product_id = OYLAMA.product_id)
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category AS KATEGORI 
    ON (KATEGORI.product_id = PRODUCT.product_id) 
WHERE KATEGORI.category_id = 69
```

Loading only 1 data query2

**query2:**

```
SELECT
    AVG(ALL OYLAMA.rating) AS ORTALAMA,
    COUNT(OYLAMA.rating) AS TOPLAMOY 
FROM oc_review AS OYLAMA 
JOIN oc_product AS PRODUCT
    ON (PRODUCT.product_id = OYLAMA.product_id) 
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category AS KATEGORI
    ON (KATEGORI.product_id = PRODUCT.product_id) 
WHERE KATEGORI.category_id = 69
```

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read that one-liner codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL creates a single group where all records are put as soon as you introduce aggregate functions such as `AVG()` and `COUNT()`. See also the question [MySQL Aggregate Functions without GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497082/mysql-aggregate-functions-without-group-by-clause) for more info.

What you might want to do is explicitly specify a `GROUP BY` clause and add the field(s) you have after `GROUP BY` also to `SELECT` for example:

```sql
SELECT 
   PRODUCT.product_id, 
   AVG(ALL OYLAMA.rating) AS ORTALAMA,
   COUNT(OYLAMA.rating) AS TOPLAMOY 
FROM oc_review AS OYLAMA 
JOIN oc_product AS PRODUCT 
   ON(PRODUCT.product_id = OYLAMA.product_id) 
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category AS KATEGORI 
   ON (KATEGORI.product_id = PRODUCT.product_id) 
WHERE KATEGORI.category_id = 69
GROUP BY PRODUCT.product_id
```

Comment: Thank you but, Print only 2 values

Comment: So it seems the category 69 only has two products which account for the two rows. What would you like to have counts and averages for? With my example you get the count and average **per product**. It seems you want something different. Maybe per product and customer? Or just per customer?

Comment: Did you notice the `GROUP BY` at the end of my example code?

Comment: Although there are more than 2 products, only 2 of them are displayed, unfortunately the sql query does not work.

Comment: Maybe try removing the `ALL` in `AVG(ALL OYLAMA.rating)`. I don't know what that is for. Also try running the query outside of PHP directly against the database to ensure it isn't PHP that's messing with the query result.