# Order output by 2 rows from different tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a `profile` and `jobs` table

Then there is the following query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(jobs.id) as jobs_completed,
      profile.rating,
      profile.id
FROM  profile
JOIN jobs ON jobs.user_id = profile.user_id AND jobs.ended <> 0
WHERE profile.whoami = 'contractor' HAVING jobs_completed > 5
ORDER BY rating DESC, jobs_completed DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

The query is working with `id` | `jobs_completed` | `rating` as input

| id | jobs_completed | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 52 | 2.8 |
| 2 | 16 | 4.6 |
| 3 | 1 | 5.0 |
| 4 | 8 | 4.7 |
| 5 | 12 | 4.3 |
| 6 | 5 | 4.9 |
| 7 | 26 | 4.4 |
| 8 | 57 | 4.9 |

The expected output is

| id | jobs_completed | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 57 | 4.9 |
| 4 | 8 | 4.7 |
| 2 | 16 | 4.6 |
| 7 | 26 | 4.4 |
| 5 | 12 | 4.3 |
| 6 | 5 | 4.9 |

The problem is that the output of this query is only producing one resulting row when I am expecting 6.

How should I write the query so that the produced output is according to the `highest ratings first` and then the `highest jobs_completed second` **ONLY WHEN** the jobs_completed is > 5 **OR** there is no `jobs_completed` that are > 5 remaining in the input ?

Comment: What about your current query is NOT working as is? Seems like you just need to reverse the fields in your `order by` clause to get `rating` as the primary sort, and `jobs_completed` seondary.  Also, it's not clear to me why you're doing a subquery instead of a join.

Comment: @Marc Updated the query as per your comment. The output is only producing one row, when I am expecting 6

Comment: @NoChance It's MariaDB-5.4 (MySQL 5.7), and no chance, limit 6 doesn't change anything! Also, it's the same column.

Comment: This will give you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497082/mysql-aggregate-functions-without-group-by-clause

Comment: @SamM may be right, in SQL aggregate functions require GROUP BY, not sure about MariaDB?

Comment: just wonder why id = 6 will be the last one. as in your order by, id = 6 should be after id = 8 isn't? because it has the same rating

Comment: is it returning six rows without the ORDER BY, and only one when ORDER BY is added? That would be a MariaDB bug then, but I assume that actually both variants return a single row only?

Comment: I figured it out. But @learning it's because of `HAVING jobs_completed > 5`. Your scenario would be true if it was `>=`